# How to calculate the longitude of a direction vector to create a vector from a point so it matches an angle with another vector in 3D

Tags: math, vector, 3d, trigonometry

Given a vector vec1 = (p1 to p2) and a normalized direction vector (dvec), I need to create a new vector vec2 = (p2 to p2+(dvec times x)), so this new vector creates a third one vec3 = (p2+(dvec times x) to p1) that forms an angle of say 90 degrees with vec1. I need the value of x, which is the magnitude of the second vector.

Thanks in advance for any solution or suggestions!

Comment: it's not clear how `vec2` enters your problem.

Comment: There are 3 vectors that form a triangle, we have vec1 and a direction, but we need to find vec2 and vec3 so vec3 forms an angle of 90 degrees with vec1. vec2 comes from p2 and goes all the way to p3 (the direction multiplied x times). If vec2 is formed from p2 and p3, then vec 3 should be from p3 to p1

Comment: Again I don't see how `vec2` is relevant to the problem. It seems you only care about `vec1` and `vec3`, or rather the angle that they form.

Comment: exactly, let's leave vec2 out of the equation, some how I thought it would help understand the problem but I can see it does the opposite, so,, any idea on how to find vec3?